# remove caracteres from an array

Tags: java, android

I use this method to remove some buttons  from a array "_wd_array" but "equal" doesn't work good for me !

```
public void remove() {
        Button[] removeBtn = { 
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.char1),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.char2),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.char3),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.char4),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.char5),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.char6),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.char7),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.char8),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.char9),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.char10),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.char11),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.char12) };

    for(int i=0;i<12;i++)

    {
         for(String s:_wd_array)
         {
             String str=removeBtn[i].getText().toString().toLowerCase();

             if( !s.equals(str) )

            {
                removeBtn[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                removeBtn[i].getBackground().setAlpha(128);
                removeBtn[value].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 

            }


         }

    }

}
```

I compare the content of _wd_array with content of button,and if it's not equal I remove the button

Any pointers appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Add a breakpoint in `if( !s.equals(str) )` ,then see `s` and `str`,then you will find why they are not equal.

Comment: thanks
already done, but hey are equal but the condition doesn't execute !!

Comment: That's impossible!Please debug and check again,especially the **blank space** and **case:upper or lower**,or you can paste content of `_wd_array ` here.

Comment: I'm also confuse every thing checked  trim; lower upper !!!!!

Comment: 1.You can follow `equals` method to look why they are not equals when debug
2.Please show more code,including `_wd_array ` and buttons

Answer (score 0):

```
 String str=removeBtn[i].getText().toString().toLowerCase();
```

this shouldnt' be getting Text of the Button. Should be getId() something like that.

```
 String str=removeBtn[i].getId(); // Maybe it is not String.
```

Comment: when I debug I get the value of removeBtn[i].getText().toString().toLowerCase()
but when it enter to equal function I don't get the match !!!

Comment: maybe there is space end of the text. After calling toLowerCase() put trim() method

Comment: Still I insist you to use getId() instead of getText()

Comment: ok, but getid returns the view identifier but I need the text inside the button int  id=_randomB[i].getId();
Button b=(Button) findViewById(id);
if(s.equals(b.getText()))

Answer (score 0):

now It Work.

```
public void removeextras() {

    int value = 0;
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(12);
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        list.add(i);
    }


    Collections.shuffle(list);


    for (int l=0; l<_wd_array.length; ++l)
    {
        _wd_array[l] = _wd_array[l].toLowerCase().trim();
    }




     for(int x=0; x<12;x++) {


        if(!list.isEmpty()) value = list.remove(0);

        if (!Arrays.asList(_wd_array).contains(
                _randomB[value].getText().toString().toLowerCase().trim())) 
        {
            _randomB[value].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


        }

    }




}
```